# How to activate telephony feature in AVD

Tags: android, telephony

I create an AVD that support Google API (level 10) because one of my activity implements MapActivity. It seems the virtual device has no telephony feature. I can't find it in feature list of PackageManager (PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY).

How to activate the feature in kind of virtual device?

Thanks.

Comment: open the emulator control there Telephony Actions is there.

Comment: Thanks. I found it in Hardware properties.

Comment: Can you please add a full answer on this? I don't see any properties.

Comment: When in eclipse for e.g. goto the DDMB perspective. On the right side (probably) you will find the "Emulator Control"

Comment: Can't see this option in Android Studio AVD Manager, anyone knows how to do it?